# RegEx to split a String either at "," or L," or ",N

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

I'm an absolute beginner on learning RegEx. I need to split a string into it's different Substrings, based on multiple conditions.

String:

```
"abc","def",NULL,"ghi",NULL,"jkl"
```

should be splitted to

```
[abc, def, NULL, ghi, NULL, jkl]
```

Currently I'm using `String[] split = line.split("\",\"");` to generate all substrings which are enclosed within **"**...**"** and seperated by **,**. This works fine, but if there is a NULL value (which is not enclosed by "..."), the substrings are splittet incorrect.

Is it possible to split the String into it's Substrings by using a RegEx which splits the String if one of the following conditions is given?

- ","
- L,"
- ",N

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like you need a CSV parser, not regex

Comment: Can you show the actual string value....with characters properly escaped?

Comment: Do your string values contain commas or why don't you use `split(",")`?

Comment: Note: Rather than split, **capture** all values *surrounded* by quotes, or all `NULL` that follow or preceed a comma

Answer (score 0):

```
    String input = "\"abc\",\"def\",NULL,NULL,\"ghi\",NULL,\"jkl\"";
    String [] split = input.split("(\",\")|(\",)|(,\")|(L,)");
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        if (split[i].startsWith("\"")) {
            split[i] = split[i].substring(1);
        }
        if (split[i].endsWith("\"")) {
            split[i] = split[i].substring(0, split[i].length() -1);
        }
        if (split[i].equals("NUL")) {
            split[i] = "NULL";
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT

```
[abc, def, NULL, NULL, ghi, NULL, jkl]
```

Comment: this messes up string values that contain a comma. Which is probably the reason why OP doesn't just use `split(",")`.

Comment: Updated to handle commas within valid strings.

Comment: now it doesnt handle something like `NULL,NULL`

Comment: I think that's the limit of regex.  The only other thing I can think to do is adding a case for (L,) and then replacing all NUL with NULL.

Answer (score 0):

We can first replace all double quotes with an empty string then we can split the resulting string with a delimiter comma. As shown below

```
String[] strArray = str.replaceAll("\"" , "").split(",");

 String str = "\"abc\",\"def\",NULL,\"ghi\",NULL,\"jkl\"";
 String[] strArray = str.replaceAll("\"" , "").split(",");
 Arrays.asList(strArray).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't need regexp. Your problem may be solved with `split()` and `replace()` methods.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "\"abc\",\"def\",NULL,\"ghi\",NULL,\"jkl\"";
    List<String> list = Arrays.stream(str.split(","))
            .map(part -> part.replace("\"", ""))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Output:

> [abc, def, NULL, ghi, NULL, jkl]

Comment: this messes up string values that contain a comma. Which is probably the reason why OP doesn't just use `split(",")`.

Comment: The argument to split is always a regex, btw